# Risks of using PHP eval for string math

Tags: php, eval

I have a question about `eval()` secourity risks

This is my own code

```
<?php

$str = 'nabi<'.$_GET['hackme']; // $_GET['hackme']=2;

$str = str_replace("nabi", 1, $str);

$hmm = eval('return ('.$str.');');

if($hmm){
    echo 'yeah';
}
else{
    echo 'no';
}
```

Result is will be:

```
yeah
```

My code workes well

It's what i want!

But i am afraid of the security risks!

Please offer a new solution

Comment: Why do you have a condition in a string? XY problem?

Comment: `if(1<2)` would be faster and cleaner.

Comment: It must string ... no way ...!

Comment: @Nabi Why must it be a string? This seems to be the XY problem

Comment: what security risks? if you do something stupid like `eval($_GET['hackme'])`, then you're completely at fault. as written above, there is ZERO risk, because you're the only one who can define what's being eval'd.

Comment: If the string can be deefined by other persons, then you have to sanitize the string first.

Comment: yes it's so stupid ... because i have a $_POST['hackme']

Comment: moment i must explaine more about my code

Comment: Kepp the following Quote in mind:

If `eval()` is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the
wrong question. -- Rasmus Lerdorf, BDFL of PHP

Comment: My god a `$_POST['hackme']`

Comment: *Never use eval. **Ever.***

Comment: @Nabi `$_GET['hackme']` And your server IP was? :D

Comment: thanks you, but have you a new solution for me ?

Comment: Yes. Your code is insecure. Do it another way.

Comment: hahaha rizer i'm testing in localhost ^^

Comment: @Nabi Before this is getting chatted, oh it did already, Why do you want to do it this way? What is your goal with this code?

Comment: Well I wouldn't throw a website online if I were you @Nabi

Comment: i'm making explode strings like in `SQL` and it's for `WHERE` slice! @Rizer123

Comment: @Nabi Edit and update your question and tell everyone it's for a MySQL `WHERE` slice. Then more programmers can help you with another solution. Tell us what you tried like the `eval()` but always tell us what you're *trying to do*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're doing is checking if something is less than 1, typecast `$_GET['hackme']` to int or double.

```
$str = 'nabi<' . (int) $_GET['hackme'];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is zero security... Every code passed to `hackme` will be executed.

Comment: have you another solution ?

Comment: If you just want to check if a given number is larger than 1 (what you are doing i guess) just `$larger = 1 < $_GET['hackme']`.

Comment: hi, is it may ? `implode(' && ', $larger);` or a code like this please