# How to convert string operation into a number?

Tags: php

I have a **string** `'1/2'` and i need to get a **float** value `0.5` from it.

Other examples:
Operation: `$operation = '5/8';`
Wanted value: `$value = 0.625;`

Comment: `list($x, $y) = explode('/', $operation); $value = $x / $y;`

Comment: Probably you're looking for the `eval` function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [calculate math expression from a string using eval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880772/calculate-math-expression-from-a-string-using-eval)

Comment: @AndyLester Bad idea to use: `evil()`

Comment: Blanket statements like "bad idea to use" aren't helpful in evaluating when one should use them.  If you want to help OP, explain the potential problems.

Comment: Or you can try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015242/how-to-evaluate-formula-passed-as-string-in-php?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: If this value is coming from user input, then eval() is potentially a very bad idea.... not only are there security risks with feeding any user input to eval (what if the user inputs `unlink(__FILE__)` or similar), but adequate error handling for malformed input to eval() is also non-existent, making it almost impossible to diagnose problems

Comment: If you want a clean, secure calculator that can handle a range of mathematical expressions (not simply division) then take a look at [how to make a calculator in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692727/how-to-make-a-calculator-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work if you only have one "/".

```
$str = '2/5';
$newStr = explode('/', $str);
echo $newStr[0]/$newStr[1];
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `eval`, also please note your are not looking for an `int` as they are whole numbers.

```
<?php

$operation = '1/2';

eval('$value = ' . $operation . ';');

echo $value;

?>
```

Comment: `evil()` is not a good idea, since when the input comes from a user he can executes every php code which he wants!

Comment: @Rizier123 I agree but the OP does not state that the input is coming from a user.

Comment: But it's always a security risk! When you don't use it you are sure that it can't be used for bad things. And as far as I know there aren't much places where you really need to use it

Comment: @Rizier123 It's not coming from a user. I'm getting it from DB.

Comment: @IlliaPotapchuk from the DB and which data do you insert there? user inputs/data?!

Comment: @Rizier123 admin inputs data there, but i see what you are talking about. I'll consider "explode" option.

Answer (score -1):

Edited.
Not elegant because `eval` is used, but working.

```
$operation = '1/2';

function stringCalc($operation){

    return eval('return '.$operation.';');
}

$value = stringCalc($operation);
```

Comment: Sorry. Answer edited, my second solution. Okay, now i see other user gives You same solution ...

Comment: Btw. I found few questions, like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999578/php-calculate-formula-in-string
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057320/php-function-to-evaluate-string-like-2-1-as-arithmetic-2-1-1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880772/calculate-math-expression-from-a-string-using-eval
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25469528/convert-string-into-math-equation
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28586982/risks-of-using-php-eval-for-string-math
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015242/how-to-evaluate-formula-passed-as-string-in-php Maybe You found better answer.